# How to iterate a vectorized if/else statement over multiple columns with a list that can change?

Tags: python, pandas

The numbers in ltlist refer to ID numbers that can change, is it possible to literate through multiple columns for the items in ltlist assume the elements in ltlist in this example aren't constant. Hope to use loop instead of vectorized if/else too but couldn't get it to work.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

ltlist = [1, 2]
org = {'ID': [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'ID2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2]}

ltlist_set = set(ltlist)
org['LT'] = np.where(org['ID'].isin(ltlist_set), org['ID'], 0)
I'll need to check the ID2 column and write the ID in, unless it already has an ID.
```

output

```
ID  ID2 LT
1   3   1
3   4   0
4   5   0
5   6   0
6   7   0
7   2   2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `0` as the default value, you can pass it as an `or` with against the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ltset = set([1, 2])
org = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'ID2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2]})

org['LT'] = 0
for col in org.columns.drop('LT'):
    org['LT'] = np.where(org[col].isin(ltset), org[col], org['LT']|0)

org 
# returns:
   ID  ID2  LT
0   1    3   1
1   3    4   0
2   4    5   0
3   5    6   0
4   6    7   0
5   7    2   2
```

This will always keep the value of the right-most column that has a value in `ltlist`.  If you want to keep the left-most column that has a value, you can just iterate over the columns in reverse.

```
for col in org.columns.drop('LT')[::-1]:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you James, your code works well when I run through the console. When I apply it to my example with actual data I get 'ltset' is not defined.